# Can a custom Yeoman generator install dependencies?

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

How can I make a custom Yeoman generator to install dependencies? I'm trying to avoid a multi-step installation process and by running 'npm install generator-example' I would like to have access to the local npm modules and bower packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the 'this.installDependencies()' Yeoman will automatically try running both npm install and bower install.

**index.js Yeoman file**

```
...
end: function () {
  this.installDependencies();
}
...
```

Please refer to [here](http://yeoman.io/authoring/dependencies.html) to get more details on handling dependencies with Yeoman.